# Log and plot temperature-time curve over given time intervall

Tags: monitoring, hardware

How can I log and plot a graph of

- all available hardware temperatures (CPU, SSD, etc).
- CPU load

over a given time (say a day or a week) in linux?

The CPU is i7 haswell if this matters, I have both, an SSD and HDD in this box.

Comment: You could use gnuplot ([example](https://securfox.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/plotting-cpu-temperature-with-gnuplot/))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code some of this yourself you should take a look at at [RRDTool](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)

You will need to script a method for inputting data to an RRD database and by running a simple command you can output png (the default) images of graphs.

Otherwise there are quite a large number of web based applications that can log and graph metrics on a server. One that immediately comes to mind is [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You also can take a look into Munin. Munin is a lightweight and easy to configurable monitoring tool.

http://munin-monitoring.org/

Comment: I just tried to configure it as described in http://b.agilob.net/linux-munin-monitor-temperatures-of-gpu-cpu-and-hdd/ however they don't show up in the web interface. Perhaps you could add some more details about how to set it up for my purpose.

Comment: http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Munin_Statistics works perfectly well for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at s-tui.
(DISCLAIMER: I created s-tui)
It lets you monitor temperature frequency and CPU utilization over time. No SSD temp at the moment.

You can check it out at https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui

Screenshot:
[image: s-tui demonstration]

Download the executable from releases, or run it with python by following the README on github.